# Can't seem to add button to another tabpage

Tags: c#, .net

I have a TabControl with three TabPages. On tabPage2 there is one button. I want to click on tabPage3 and see this button. I've searched around and the code below is susposed to work but when I click on tabPage3 from tabPage2, I don't see the button.

I must be missing something else?

Thanks for any help...

```
    private void tabPage3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.button1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is going to cause you problems.  Add a second button, or, if a single button must be visible, place it outside the TabControl altogether.  Making controls hop around like that is a bad idea.

Comment: Ahhh...I see...ok, I will move the single button outside of the tabcontrol...thanks...

Comment: OK, I moved the button outside of the tabpage. However, when I try to set its location (.left and .top) in relation to the tabpage, it looks like its being located by ref to the form, not the tabpage!

Comment: You'll have to post some code and a description.  Yes, it will be positioned relative to its container, not a sibling control.  If you want relativity, stick all of it in a TableLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SelectedIndexChanged() event:

```
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(this.button1);
    }
```

If you only wanted it to move between tabs 2 and 3 specifically:

```
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 1 || tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        }
    }
```

As DonBoitnott pointed out, though, it can cause problems depending on how the form is laid out.